# Macro assignment problem

Tags: macros

```
\docuentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}%

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tmpa}{}
\newcommand{\tmpb}{}
\newcommand{\tmpc}{}

\renewcommand{\tmpc}{tmpc1}  
\renewcommand{\tmpa}{\tmpc}
\renewcommand{\tmpb}{\tmpc}
\noindent tmpa: \tmpa \\
tmpb: \tmpb \\
tmpc: \tmpc \\
\renewcommand{\tmpc}{tmpc2}
tmpa: \tmpa \\
tmpb: \tmpb \\
tmpc: \tmpc 

\end{document}
```

Result:

tmpa: tmpc1

tmpb: tmpc1

tmpc: tmpc1

---

tmpa: tmpc2

tmpb: tmpc2

tmpc: tmpc2

Changing the value of `tmpc` changes the values of the other two variables. How can I assign only the value of `tmpc` without this pointer like effect?

Comment: Replace `\renewcommand{\tmpa}{\tmpc} \renewcommand{\tmpb}{\tmpc}` by `\let\tmpa\tmpc \let\tmpb\tmpc`. And take a look at "TeX by Topic" (`texdoc texbytopic`)

Comment: It is difficult to understand why you use `\tmpc` in `\tmpa` and `\tmpb` if you do not want this `pointer effect'.
Just define another command ?!
You should provide more context so that one can think of a workaround. Right now, your problem appears rather unclear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When TeX finds a macro it expands it to its *current meaning*; so with

```
\newcommand{\tmpa}{}
\newcommand{\tmpb}{}
\newcommand{\tmpc}{}

\renewcommand{\tmpc}{tmpc1}  
\renewcommand{\tmpa}{\tmpc}
\renewcommand{\tmpb}{\tmpc}
```

when `\tmpa` is found, it's replaced first by `\tmpc` and then by `tmpc1` (which is what `\tmpc` is defined to expand to).

If you want to *freeze* the meaning, then `\let` is the instruction to use:

```
\let\tmpa\tmpx
```

will assign to `\tmpa` the current meaning of `\tmpx` and subsequent changes to the latter command will not influence the meaning of `\tmpa`.

There's no "LaTeX interface" to `\let`, because such commands are intended to be used by "programmers" rather than "users".